# Continue for loop in pandas df based on single row inputs

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a rather big dataframe containing data which is 'known' and 'unknown'. I am trying to create a for-loop (or a different solution) that iterates through a specific dataframe column and fills in a value every time a 'known' value is found.  Once this value is found the loop has to fill in the value until the next known value is found. After this new known value is found the loop fills in this new known value etc. I cannot delete the unknown data.

The for loop that I currently have is able to append the known value to the row its in, but I do not know how fill in this value until the next known value and repeat this step.

```py
import pandas as pd
example = [{'A':"Value_01"}, {'A':"unknown_x"}, {'A':"Value_02"}, {'A':"random_y"}, {'A':"dontknow_1"}, {'A':"random_x"}, {'A':"Value_03"}, {'A':"dontknow_2"}, {'A':"dontknow_3"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(example)

values = []
for row in df['A']:
    if "Value_01" in row:
        values.append("Value_01")
    elif "Value_02" in row:
        values.append("Value_02")
    elif "Value_03" in row:
        values.append("Value_03")
```

The example and desired output:

```
df                       
Input                   Desired
-------                 --------
Value_01                Value_01
unknown                 Value_01
Value_02                Value_02
unknown                 Value_02
unknown                 Value_02
unknown                 Value_02
Value_03                Value_03
unknown                 Value_03
unknown                 Value_03
```

Since I am using this piece of python code in a different software program I am only able to use native python and the following packages: matplotlib, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, seaborn and statsmodels. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have answered your question, however I believe that my method may or may not work depending on the nature of your data. Please, if this does not answer your question edit your question with an example of the data you are using, I will be happy to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to use a loop. You can use the methods that incorporates pandas. In the case you mention you can do the following

You can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandasSeries.str.contains.html) Fill values unknown with [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
new_df=df.where(df['A'].str.contains('Value')).ffill()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
          A
0  Value_01
1  Value_01
2  Value_02
3  Value_02
4  Value_02
5  Value_02
6  Value_03
7  Value_03
8  Value_03
```

---

Also you can use [DataFrame.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.mask(~df['A'].str.contains('Value')).ffill()
```

---

**if what you have is a list of known values ​​you can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) as @splash58 suggested**:

```
new_df=df.where(df['A'].isin(['Value_01','Value_02', 'Value_03'])).ffill()
```

Comment: if values are not so regular `df.where(df.isin(['Value_01','Value_02', 'Value_03'])).ffill()`